# Parsing response body when it contains only one string value

Tags: http, angular

I am using **Angular 2**, and I want to parse the response to http POST method. However, the method returns a `String` value, and not an `object`.

If I try to extract the response by using `Response.json()`, it returns an error.

Any suggestions how to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

Try `Response::text()` instead:

```
.map(res => res.text())
```

Comment: I like how you literally copy/pasted my answer :D
Have my upvote, though!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Response::_body` instead.

```js
.map(res => res._body)
```

---

> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zcoqxhiZHtjoGqVNVE6L?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: `_body` is a private member of `Response`, `tsc` complains. However, it works fine.

Comment: A "prublic" member then, I guess!

Comment: error: `[0] app/test.service.ts(22,29): error TS2341: Property '_body' is private and only accessible within class 'Response'.`

Comment: Haha, I was joking, my friend!